# How to change the status if I clicked on a close button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement like there are so many status are there as well as one close icon is there near by status. for example please refer the below image.

[image]

Here is the sample code

```
props.products.map((val, i)=>(
          val.status === "cancelled" ? (<td><span className="Cancelled">{val.status}</span></td>)
          <td className={val.status === "completed" ? "success">{val.status}
                  &nbsp; &nbsp;
            {val.status != "completed"? <span onClick={() =>this.closeIcon(i)} className="Cancel"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>: null}<br/></td>)}             

            ))
```

`When I click on close icon button the status will be changed to "wait"`

1. So anyone can know the solution of this problem

   ```
    Thanks in advance.
   ```

Comment: You're mapping over `props.products` so you need to call a function also passed down as prop to send a message to the parent component. You can do this inside `closeIcon`. In the parent component, you then update the products array based on `i`. Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: can u plz update the code

Comment: No, what exactly are you stuck on? Having an array as state?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to have a setter method passed as a prop as `setProducts`

```
setStatus = (i, status) => {
    this.props.setProducts(
        props.products.map((item, itemIndex) => {
            if (itemIndex === i) {
                return { ...item, status };
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        })
    );
};
```

add click handler to icon
`onClick={() =>this.setStatus(i, "wait")`

```
props.products.map((val, i)=>(
          val.status === "cancelled" ? (<td><span className="Cancelled">{val.status}</span></td>)
          <td className={val.status === "completed" ? "success">{val.status}
                  &nbsp; &nbsp;
            {val.status != "completed"? <span onClick={() =>this.closeIcon(i)} className="Cancel"><i class="fas fa-times-circle" onClick={() =>this.setStatus(i, "wait")></i></span>: null}<br/></td>)}             

            ))
```